# AJAX Laravel - Send form data to email

Tags: php, ajax, forms, laravel, email

```
  Now i send my form data to email account, exemple@google.com, using function: 


         public function ContactExemple()
            {
                $email = Input::get('email');
                $subiect = Input::get('phone');
                Mail::send('email', [
                    'name'=>Input::get('name'),
                    'email'=>$email,
                    'phone'=>$phone,
                    'msg'=>Input::get('msg')
                ], function($m) use($email, $subiect) {
                    $m->from($email);
                    $m->to(' exemple@google.com')->subject($subiect);
                });
                return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#contact_form")->with('message', 'THANKS FOR YOUR MSG!');
            }
```

And my VIEW:

```
  <form action="{{url('/'.$lang)}}" method="POST" >
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input type="text"  name="name">
    <input type="email" name="email" type="email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" type="text">
    <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
                   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">     </input>
                 @if(Session::has('message')) <p class="alert alert-info">    {{Session::get('message')}} </p> @endif
  </form>
```

Routes:

```
 Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
 Route::post('/', 'HomeController@ContactExemple');
```

I need to do this using AJAX, but can't find anything that can help me to do this, there is a lot of examples with simple ajax post request, but i need to integrate it with sending to my email account this form data.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the way you receive your data on you ContactExemple from your controller to access the post data send it from your view with js, should be something like this:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $name = $request->input('name');

    //
 }
```

You should check the documentation, to check how you should handle the data 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $("#myform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/my/url/",
      data: form.serialize(),
    });
  });
});
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('/my/url/','HomeController@conatact_example');
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" >
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> {!! csrf_field() !!}
  <input type="text"  name="name">
  <input type="email" name="email" type="email">
  <input type="text" name="phone" type="text">
  <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></input>
  @if(Session::has('message')) <p class="alert alert-info">{{Session::get('message')}} </p> @endif
</form>
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function conatact_example(Request $request){
   $name = $request->input('name');
   // your logic
}
```